# Node Command(Node App.js) is not working in visual studio Code

Tags: node.js

Iam a beginner in node, I have used VS Code for this

```
1.Installed Node
2. created an App.js file with code like below.
3.navigated to that directory and typed "node App.js"
```

Result : nothing happened and no error also, but a new line is created

Since i just  clicked debug option and selected node.js environment it is running fine

Just wondering why it not working for the first time.(Using that command)

App.js file

```
const http = require("http");
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

//Create HTTP server and listen on port 3000 for requests
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  //Set the response HTTP header with HTTP status and Content type
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('custom\n');
});

//listen for request on port 3000, and as a callback function have the port listened on logged
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Whats the output of the console when yout type node App.js?

Comment: "[Info  - 11:50:14 PM] Using tsserver from: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js
[Info  - 11:50:14 PM] Forking TSServer
PATH: undefined"      only thing i have got in console